# Getting double from a number

Tags: lua

I got a number that returns in seconds, I want to know is there any possible way to get double from this number and add it to string part? Here is the code:

```
local time = os.time() - LastTime()
local min = time / 60
min = tostring(min)
min = string.gsub(min, ".", ":")
print("You got "..min.." min!")
```

The above file returns: You got :::: min!

All i am looking for is convert seconds to minutes and seconds (More like 2:23)

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `math.modf` function.

```
time = os.time()
--get minutes and franctions of minutes
minutes, seconds = math.modf(time/60)
--change fraction of a minute to seconds
seconds = math.floor((seconds * 60) + 0.5)

--print everything in a printf-like way :)
print(string.format("You got %d:%d min!", minutes, seconds))
```

Answer (score 2):

`min = string.gsub(min, ".", ":")`

This code is replacing all characters with a colon.  This is because your second parameter is a regular expression, where a period matches any character.  You could try escaping it with a backslash, i.e.

`min = string.gsub(min, "%.", ":")`

However this will still give you the fractional number of minutes, not the number of seconds.  Despite you saying you want `3:63` I doubt this is the case as it's an invalid time.

Try:

`print(string.format("%d:%d", math.floor(time/60), time%60))`

Answer (score 1):

Try and play with os.date:

```
print(os.date("%M:%S",500))
```

> 08:20